Trouble with simplifying $e^{\pi i(\beta+\beta')}(e^{2\pi i(\alpha+\gamma)}-e^{-2\pi i \beta'})$
So I have the following computation
$$
e^{\pi i(\beta+\beta')}(e^{2\pi i(\alpha+\gamma)}-e^{-2\pi i \beta'}),
$$
everything is a constant. For a bit of context this is a computation appearing in finding the monodromy of the hipergeometric differential equation.
And trying to simplify leaves me stuck at
$$
e^{\pi i(\beta+\beta')}(e^{2\pi i(\alpha+\gamma)}-e^{-2\pi i \beta'})=e^{\pi i(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}e^{\pi i(\alpha+\beta'+\gamma)}-e^{\pi i(\beta-\beta')}.
$$
I need to arrive at something like
$$
 2\pi ie^{\pi i(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}\sin\pi(\alpha+\beta'+\gamma).
$$
Any hints or suggestions?

$$e^{\pi i(\beta+\beta')}(e^{2\pi i(\alpha+\gamma)}-e^{-2\pi i \beta'})$$
$$=e^{i\pi(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}(e^{i\pi(\alpha+\gamma+\beta')}-e^{-i\pi(\alpha+\gamma+\beta')})$$
$$=e^{i\pi(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}2i\sin\pi(\alpha+\gamma+\beta').$$
More generally,
$$e^{ix}-e^{iy}=e^{i(x+y)/2}(e^{i(x-y)/2}-e^{-i(x-y)/2})=e^{i(x+y)/2}2i\sin((x-y)/2).$$

Indeed. It might be hard for a novice to "guess" this sort of balanced adjustment to find a sine-function (or cosine, with a plus...), without knowing the trick already. :)
